# How to activate Python virtual environment without admin privileges?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

Python 3.8.3, Windows 10

I created a virtual environment using Python's virtualenv package, with this command:

```
python -m venv C:/<Path>
```

Now when I try to activate the virtual environment with:

```
.\C:/<Path>/activate.bat
```

I get the following error message:

```
This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
```

I unfortunately have no way of bypassing the admin blocks on this computer, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to switch symbol `/` on this `\`

```
.\C:<Path>\activate.bat
```

In windows env activated like this

```
%venv_folder%\Scripts\activate.bat
```

or u can use pipenv

1.

```
pip install pipenv
```

2.

```
pipenv shell
```

3.

```
pipenv install <lib_name>
```

4. For activation env use

```
exit
```

Comment: used pipenv. pipenv shell creates a venv if there isn't one, and activates it all at once, without asking for admin permission.